# Counting the number of hydrogen bonds of multiple PDB files

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, pdb

I've been trying to figure out a systematic way to count the number of hydrogen bonds for multiple PDB files.

DSSP shows me the total number of hydrogen bonds when I make `dssp.exe 1A11.pdb`, giving me the total number of `24` (am I correct, ok?)

```
24 96.0   TOTAL NUMBER OF HYDROGEN BONDS OF TYPE O(I)-->H-N(J)  , SAME NUMBER PER 100 RESIDUES
```

But when I run this command in R:

```
> require(biod3d)
> x=dssp(read.pdb("1A11"), full=T)
```

it doesn't look to have the number of hydrogen bonds. It shows this:

```
> x$hbonds
     BP1 BP2 NH-O.1   E1 O-HN.1   E2 NH-O.2   E3 O-HN.2   E4 ChainBP1 ChainBP2 Chain1 Chain2 Chain3 Chain4
1-A   NA  NA     NA  0.0      5 -2.1     NA  0.0      4 -0.3     <NA>     <NA>   <NA>      A   <NA>      A
2-A   NA  NA      3 -0.2      6 -1.5      4 -0.2      7 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
3-A   NA  NA      4 -0.2      7 -1.8      5 -0.2      2 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
4-A   NA  NA      1 -0.3      8 -1.5      6 -0.2      7 -0.6     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
5-A   NA  NA      1 -2.1      9 -1.9      6 -0.2     10 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
6-A   NA  NA      2 -1.5     10 -1.3      1 -0.3      5 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
7-A   NA  NA      3 -1.8     11 -1.3      4 -0.6      5 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
8-A   NA  NA      4 -1.5     12 -1.2      3 -0.2      6 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
9-A   NA  NA      5 -1.9     13 -1.1      4 -0.2      7 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
10-A  NA  NA      6 -1.3     14 -2.3      5 -0.2     13 -0.4     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
11-A  NA  NA      7 -1.3     15 -1.8     12 -0.2     16 -0.3     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
12-A  NA  NA      8 -1.2     16 -1.8     13 -0.2     11 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
13-A  NA  NA      9 -1.1     17 -2.4     10 -0.4     18 -0.5     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
14-A  NA  NA     10 -2.3     18 -1.6     15 -0.2     13 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
15-A  NA  NA     11 -1.8     19 -1.8     17 -0.2     20 -0.5     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
16-A  NA  NA     12 -1.8     20 -0.8     17 -0.3     14 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
17-A  NA  NA     13 -2.4     21 -1.9     19 -0.2     16 -0.3     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
18-A  NA  NA     14 -1.6     22 -2.0     13 -0.5     21 -1.0     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
19-A  NA  NA     15 -1.8     23 -2.0     20 -0.3     24 -0.3     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
20-A  NA  NA     16 -0.8     24 -1.5     15 -0.5     19 -0.3     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
21-A  NA  NA     17 -1.9     25 -1.0     18 -1.0     19 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
22-A  NA  NA     18 -2.0     25 -0.3     23 -0.2     20 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
23-A  NA  NA     19 -2.0     22 -0.2     18 -0.3     21 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
24-A  NA  NA     20 -1.5     23 -0.2     19 -0.3     22 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
25-A  NA  NA     21 -1.0     23 -0.2     22 -0.3     24 -0.2     <NA>     <NA>      A      A      A      A
```

So, my question: Is the total number of hydrogen bonds hidden somewhere in this output or somewhere else (or doesn't exist)?

If I manage to count the number of hydrogen bonds in a single PDB using Bio3D and R, then I can create a loop and iterate over all remainder PDB files.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an initial solution, but can be improved:

```
out = system2("f:/stride/stride.exe", "f:/stride/1a11.pdb -h", stdout=T)
nh  = strsplit(out[grepl("HBT", out)], "  ")[[1]][2]
print(nh) # Output: 26 (hydrogen bonds)
```

I compiled an Windows version of Stride and uploaded here:
http://lcrserver.icmc.usp.br/~daniel/bin/stride.exe

Comment: I am also interested in this approach. @daniel-bonetti could you make a Linux binary for STRIDE? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, no need, I managed to download and compile it.

Answer (score 1):

The number of hydrogen bonds cannot actually be said from software only inferred. But you could try using STRIDE (http://structure.usc.edu/stride/) which takes the file name with a -h flag to output the number of hydrogen bonds. You could then write a small shell script which would pass in each file and store the data you wanted in whatever format you liked.

Comment: It's true! I thought it could exist a direct way to do that :)